# jQuery and CSS not working when generated from PHP

Tags: php, jquery, css

I'm trying to create a follow button (like twitter) and it's largely working, however when I generate the HTML from PHP script it's not.

Here's the fiddle to show it working: http://jsfiddle.net/MCam435/HpAWH/10/

Works wonderfully :)

However when I generate it from PHP:

PHP Script

```
function getTalent($row) {

     return "<div class='talent_result_wrapper' data-experience='" . $row['divTagExp'] . "' data-salary='" . $row['divTagSal'] . "'>
      <div class='talent_result_header'>
        <span class='talent_result_head'>ID: </span>" . $row['CandidateID'] . "
      </div>
        <ul>
          <li><strong>Resides:  </strong>" . $row['Town'] . "</li>
          <li><strong>Salary Required:  </strong>£" . $row['SalaryMin'] . "</li>
          <li><strong>Experience:  </strong>" . $row['CandidateExperience'] . " Years </li>
          <li><strong>Industy:  </strong>" . $row['PrimarySector'] . "</li>
          <li><strong>Specialism:  </strong>" . $row['PrimarySector'] . "</li>
          <br>
          <div id='follow1'><a href='#' class='follow' id='1'><span class='follow_b'> + Tag </span></a></div>
          <div id='remove1' style='display:none'><a href='' class='remove' id='1'><span class='remove_b'> - UnTag </span></a></div>
      </div>";
    }
```

Main Page

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result2)) {
                echo getTalent($row);
            }
```

The switching between div's doesn't work, even though the output is exactly the same?

Comment: What shows the error console?

Comment: Any chance you're sending this through ajax?

Comment: Nothing shows in the console. @GrahamWalters how do you mean? The results in the div are being populated with ajax. Nothing is being sent back though at the moment.

Comment: After calling this function, try to echo out the button toggle part.

Comment: You need to bind event on dynamically create elements. Please check the answer below.

Comment: How has this got anything to do with event delegation when it's a server-side script that adds elements to the page?

Comment: You must post the markup too

Comment: @Archer: Ahh... Crap. I removed my answer.

Comment: @KishorSubedi Heh - it's the curse of an unclear question with server-side script.  Everyone jumps on the obvious delegation issue, probably because there's about 1000 questions a day that *are* about it :p

Comment: @Archer: You got it bro, also every one is in rush to answer first.

Comment: @KishorSubedi Sad, but true.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't have multiple elements with the same ID on a page.

```
     <div id='follow1'><a href='#' class='follow' id='1'><span class='follow_b'> + Tag </span></a></div>
     <div id='remove1' style='display:none'><a href='' class='remove' id='1'><span class='remove_b'> - UnTag </span></a></div>
```

You need to give those elements all unique IDs.  It will work if there is only 1 instance of this on the page, but as soon as you add more than 1 it will start to fail.  That's why it works in your example, but not when you use PHP.

Comment: Ahhh... Yeh this was a pretty stupid mistake... I'll check on my code to verify that's the cause, and update. Thank you.

Comment: Updated the PHP script to give each one a unique ID. Worked straight away (of course). Thank you.

Comment: It's an easy mistake to make.  Glad I could help :)